# How to wait main thread until async task is completed in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have an async task which will take longer than main thread. Main thread is finished before async task and I do not see results from Async task for example I don't see DB record which async task should insert.

Here is my code

Framework 4.5

```
    public void Load(int id)
    {
        Task asynctask1;
        asynctask1 = CallWithAsync(id); // this is async task 
        task2(); // main thread
        task3(); // main thread

    }
    private async static Task CallWithAsync(int id)
    {
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            result = await InsertDataAsync(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do some error logging
        }
        //return result;

    }
    static Task<string> InsertDataAsync(int id)
    {
        return Task.Run<string>(() =>
        {
            return InsertData(id);
        });
    }
    static string InsertData(int id)
    {

        try
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);//we have some code here which takes longer
            //code to insert DB record

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do some error logging
        }


        return "success";

    }


    public void task2()
    {
        //some thing
    }
    public void task3()
    {
        //some thing
    }
```

Comment: `await asynctask1;` ?

Comment: @zerkms The `Load` method isn't marked as `async`, so `await` isn't an option in this case.

Comment: I usually use a WaitHandle : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WillRay `Wait()` may potentially deadlock (for this very code), so I'd rather change the `Load` signature if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for the task to be completed at the end of the method:

```
public void Load(int id)
{
    Task asynctask1;
    asynctask1 = CallWithAsync(id);
    task2();
    task3();
    asynctask1.Wait(); // wait for async task to complete
}
```

You could also use the `await` keyword if you add the `async` keyword to the `Load` method itself.

Comment: I tried this but execution is not going beyond wait().

Comment: @Abbi Are you trying it with the sample code that you've provided in the question or the full code? Execution will not proceed until `CallWithAsync` is completed.

Comment: Yes I was executing full code. I made Load method Async and it is working. Thanks everyone for your feedback.

Comment: Great !!  Working like charm. Thanks @WillRay

Answer (score 0):

Make Load async and await the call? You can have an async void method, though would be better if it was an async Task and you awaited it further up the call chain.

```
public async void Load(int id)
{
  await CallWithAsync(id); // this is async task 
  task2(); // main thread
  task3(); // main thread
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `Load` method `async` by awaiting on `asynctask1` after calls to `task2()` and `task3()`. Note, `Load` method now returns `Task`  instead of `void`

```
public async Task Load(int id)
{
    Task asynctask1;
    asynctask1 = CallWithAsync(id); // this is async task 
    task2(); // main thread
    task3(); // main thread
    var result = await asynctask1;
    Console.Writeline(result); //verify returned value of asynctask1 task 
}

private async static Task<string> CallWithAsync(int id)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        result = await InsertDataAsync(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //do some error logging
    }
    return result;

}
```